# Generic extending class with companion object in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin

I write the following code but it doesn't works because I get an **unresolved reference** error.

```
class Chromosome {
    constructor() {}

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): Chromosome {
            return Chromosome()
        }
    }
}

class Population<T>(size: Int) where T: Chromosome {
    var population: Array<T> = Array(size, { _ -> T.newInstance() })
}
```

I want a generic type T that extends a certain class or interface. I need to call a static factory methods because I cannot write `T()` in *Array* class constructor. Are there any way to wrap *Array* class calling a default constructor?

I tried with a different approach but it still not works. This time I get an **Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead** error.

```
class Population<T>(size: Int, init: () -> T) where T: Chromosome {
    var population: Array<T> = Array(size, { _ -> init() })
}
```

Comment: I think `ClassY` is `Class Y`. Right?

Comment: This is as problematic in Java as in Kotlin. How would you implement this exactly in Java?

Comment: @tynn Good question. I tried to implement in Java but it doesn't work too. So you are right when you say that this is problematic in both languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Array` type acts the same as the array in *Java*. Therefore it is special and does not work well with generics. Instead you should use a *Java* `List` approach. This means to use `MutableList` in *Kotlin*.

```
class Population<T: Chromosome>(size: Int, factory: () -> T) {
    var population = MutableList(size, { factory() })
}
```

Also be sure to implement `Chromosome` as open or abstract class. Otherwise you wouldn't need to make the population generic and the `Array` approach would work again.

Answer (score -1):

You can try your `Population` class as code like below:

```
 class Population<T : Class<*>>(size: Int) where T: Chromosome {
...
}
```

Using above code your `Population` class can able to get the generic type of class.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but it doesn't work. I get these errors: **Upper bounds of T have empty intersection** and **Only one of the upper bounds can be a class**.